# Shift in course each of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm trying to animate the `margin-left` of each div one after another:

```
var array = ['#lazer', '#ergonomic', '#myagkaya-chast', '#krepkost'];
var i = 0;
while (i < array.length) {
    array[i].animate({
        marginLeft: '40px'
    }, 1000, function () {
        i++;
    });
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://fiddle.jshell.net/QRr7H/1)

Comment: Could you explain your problem a little more please?

Comment: @imtheman I need to animate marginLeft of each element in the array one after another

Comment: @imtheman I'am trying to create animation like here http://aino.com/projects

Comment: Havent tried it, but probably scope issue with i variable

Comment: sorry, my english is terrible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to remove the `i++` from the animate callback since it is asynchronous, also rather then extend the animate effect use `jQuery.delay()` to offset the start time.

```
var array = ['#lazer', '#ergonomic', '#myagkaya-chast', '#krepkost'];
var i = 0;
var delay = 100;

while (i < array.length) {
    $(array[i]).delay(delay * i).animate({
        marginLeft: '40px'
    }, "linear");
    i++;
}
```

[**Demo**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/QRr7H/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You forgot your jQuery object wrapper `$(array[i])`. Also, if you're not going to use a for loop like shown, put your `i` variable outside the `animate()` function.

```
var array = ['#lazer', '#ergonomic', '#myagkaya-chast', '#krepkost'];
for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    $(array[i]).animate({
        marginLeft: '40px'
    }, 1000);
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://fiddle.jshell.net/QRr7H/4/)

Comment: this is not exactly what I need. circles are moving simultaneously. I need that they would animate one after the other